# creating groupbox with controls when clicking a button

Tags: button, for-loop, dynamically-generated, groupbox

i want to create a groupbox that contain a label and a textbox with in just clicking to a button 'Add' and it will be a for loop. how much i click that will appear groupbox in C#

Answer (score 0):

You can add control and groupboxes to a form by doing the following.

```
        private int yAxis;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          var grp = new GroupBox();
          yAxis += 50;
          grp.Location = new Point(0, yAxis);
          this.Controls.Add(grp);
          var btn = new Button();
          grp.Controls.Add(btn);   
        }
```

Comment: but i want to add GroupBoxes and its controls like textbox,label dynamically too